# Asynchronous web Post API call from c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am writing the code as :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(qry);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ContentLength = 0;

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(crsAdapterXML.ToString());
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();
Stream objStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
result = Convert.ToString(objReader.ReadLine());
```

I need to make this call asyncronous. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Using the above code I can make a Web request to the API and got the result successfully. I have to call this request hundred of times at a time. Every time when I call this I need to wait for the result to make a second call.
I just want that I can call this request without waiting for the result. Just like using async and await. But unable to implement async and await that in my code.

Comment: Have you tried using GetResponseAsync instead of GetResponse? Or use HttpClient and its methods to reduce the required code and stream handling

Comment: @ConvictionInfoTech Can you explain why you can't use async-await in your code?  There are Task based methods on request/response stream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `HttpWebRequest` is kinda old school way of doing HTTP requests nowadays.
There are libraries which provide better APIs to do this.

I recommend you to try Microsoft's [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (System.Net.Http) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

There are probably many more but those are the ones I know and didn't have problems with.

Both provide async API so you can asynchronously wait for a response.

I don't have much experience with `HttpWebRequest` but it seems it also exposes async variations of its methods like `GetResponseAsync` or `GetRequestStreamAsync`